# How can i load result from a MySQL database to a website

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I am trying to get the results of my database and print them online but I'm doing something wrong. I'm using xampp to host my database which is in MySQL.I don't know if the problem is at my java code or in my HTML. I tried the code below but when I go to the website and press the button that returns the results it isn't working. So I can't understand if I the problem is in the connection with the database or with the HTML code. Here is the java code

```
  public class CloudServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out;
        out=null;

        String docType=
                "!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC\"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.1"+ "transitional//EN\"\n";

        String title="results";
        String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";

        String query = "Select * FROM TRENDS ORDER BY NUM DESC"; 

        showTable(url,query, out);
        resp.getWriter();

    }
    public void showTable(String url,String query, PrintWriter out){

        int num=0;
        String Name=null;

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (url);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("");
                sb.append(rs.getInt(2));
                String strI = sb.toString();
                Name = rs.getString(1);
                out.print(strI+Name);
            }
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: if you can't explain HOW this code isn't working, why should we try and GUESS what the problem is?

Comment: Ok yeah sorry my mistake i'll fix it

Comment: I think you will have NPE at `out.print()`

Comment: as commented above, maybe NPE on `out.print()`?

Comment: Does the servlet container you use report any error? Any stacktrace? Where is the HTML code you mention that may contain an error? Generally speaking, with a debugger you could check if your ResultSet retrieves data, if generated http request and html is OK looking into the http request and response using e.g. Firefox developer tools.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot i'll try those things and i'll see what can i do! 
Καλό βράδυ

Answer (score 0):

Try put `ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();` instead of `PrintWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter out;
    out = null;

    String docType = "!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC\"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.1" + "transitional//EN\"\n";

    String title = "results";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
    String query = "Select * FROM TRENDS ORDER BY NUM DESC";

    // if you do not perform this step,the parameter "out" in the showTable is null
    // and may throws NullPointerException
    out = resp.getWriter();
    showTable(url, query, out);

    // I think your problem is in this line
    // resp.getWriter();
}
```

Comment: Do you think that if i make a JSP it would work?
I think the problem isn't java but Html